# Abstracting Entity Framework in Domain Driven Design (how to avoid IDbSet)

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I am trying to use Entity Framework in a Domain Driven Design project.

In my understanding, the `Domain` layer should be ignorant of any persistence implementation. So I have two interfaces - `IRepository` and `IUnitOfWork`. I provide the implementation in the `Data` layer.

My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to avoid using Entity Framework's `IDbSet` in either `IRepository` or `IUnitOfWork`.

I would like to ask 2 questions - how could I abstract Entity Framework from the `Domain` layer? And - could I avoid this issue completely if I switch to NHibernate? Many Thanks.

Comment: You can use IQueryable instead of IDbSet

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but then I wouldn't be able to either add or insert data. Because I would need a reference to a DbSet<TEntity>.

Comment: You  can cast it back to IDbSet if uou wan in your Repository méthod impelmentation BTW.

Comment: Why can't you abstract out `IDbSet`? Show some code to make your point.

Comment: @user4811392: Could you elaborate on why you can't avoid IDbSet in repo/uow? People do it daily, without much effort. The add/update you mention don't need dbsets (they need dbsets in implementation but not in abstraction). What specific issue you have then?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorZychla, I actually read your blog. Now things are clear to me. I'll keep my reference to IDbSet in IEntityFrameworkUnitOfWork in the Data layer with the Entity Framework implementation. In turn, I have a persistence-ignorant IUnifOfWork in the Domain layer, which IEntityFrameworkUnitOfWork implements. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

On your repository interface, define lookup methods such as

```
Task<MyAggregate> FindById(MyAggregateId id);
```

and mutator methods such as

```
Task Update(MyAggregate aggregate);
```

This makes clear that the repository uses domain objects on its interface - encapsulation accomplished!

If you later switch to NHibernate, you need to change the following in the domain and the service layer: **Nothing**.

Note: The `Task<T>` and `Task` return values are only there because repository interaction is best implemented asynchronously. If you don't need/want that, you don't need the task wrappers either.

Comment: Very nice! I'd also add that the repository classes which **implements** the repo interfaces would stand in the Infra/Data layer together with EF, just to clear to others who might read. If he switches to NHibernate, he just changes the repositoty class code, without worring about the Domain interfaces, like you mentioned.